# azure management client doesn't return any resource group

Tags: c#, azure

I am new to azure. I am trying to create ResourceGroup then trying to deploy a VM. But I am getting exception during accessing resourcegroups.

I am following MSDN example given here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/csharp-template

I tried different subscription but no luck. Couldn't find any pointers online for this issue or I might have missed. If you could help me please let me know.

Thanks.

```
//AppId,Key,TenetId are correct
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory
                .FromServicePrincipal(ApplicationID, Key, TenetID,
                    new AzureEnvironment()
                    {
                        AuthenticationEndpoint = @"https://login.windows.net/",
                        ManagementEndpoint = @"https://management.core.windows.net/",
                        ResourceManagerEndpoint = @"https://management.azure.com/",
                        GraphEndpoint = @"https://graph.windows.net/",
                    });

 var azure = Azure
                .Configure()
                .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                .Authenticate(credentials)
                .WithSubscription(AzureProperties.SubscriptionId);

            var groupName = "MyresourceGroup1";
            var location = Region.USWest;

//Exception comes at here.
            var resourceGroup = azure.ResourceGroups.Define(groupName)
                .WithRegion(location)
                .Create();
```

//Exception details.

```
System.ArgumentNullException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.String.EndsWith(String value, StringComparison comparisonType)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Authentication.AzureCredentials.<ProcessHttpRequestAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.ResourceGroupsOperations.<CreateOrUpdateWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.ResourceGroupImpl.<CreateResourceAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.ResourceActions.Creatable`4.<Microsoft-Azure-Management-ResourceManager-Fluent-Core-ResourceActions-IResourceCreator<IResourceT>-CreateResourceAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.DAG.CreatorTaskItem`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.DAG.TaskGroupBase`1.<ExecuteNodeTaskAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.Extensions.Synchronize[TResult](Func`1 function)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.ResourceActions.Creatable`4.Create()
   at pvt_CreateVM.AzureVMManager.CreateVM()
   at pvt_CreateVM.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think code is currently failing because you haven't set any value for `KeyVaultSuffix` property for `AzureEnvrionment` that you have initialized.

It's a guess looking at the error info you have shared but I say this after looking at the relevant source code for Azure Management Libraries for .NET

(on a side note it's awesome that anyone can do that.. here is a [**link**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/master/src/ResourceManagement/ResourceManager/Authentication/AzureCredentials.cs))

```
    public async override Task ProcessHttpRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var adSettings = new ActiveDirectoryServiceSettings
        {
            AuthenticationEndpoint = new Uri(Environment.AuthenticationEndpoint),
            TokenAudience = new Uri(Environment.ManagementEndpoint),
            ValidateAuthority = true
        };
        string url = request.RequestUri.ToString();
        if (url.StartsWith(Environment.GraphEndpoint, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            adSettings.TokenAudience = new Uri(Environment.GraphEndpoint);
        }

        string host = request.RequestUri.Host;

        // I guess this is where your code is failing currently. 
        if (host.EndsWith(Environment.KeyVaultSuffix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
```

**How to fix**

Unless there is a good reason, I would not initialize `AzureEnvironment` object and instead use the values already available, as that would make sure all required properties have correct values.

Example: `AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud`. Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.fluent.azureenvironment?view=azure-dotnet) for all possible values

Change this code where you initialize AzureEnvironment

```
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory
            .FromServicePrincipal(ApplicationID, Key, TenetID,
                new AzureEnvironment()
                {
                    AuthenticationEndpoint = @"https://login.windows.net/",
                    ManagementEndpoint = @"https://management.core.windows.net/",
                    ResourceManagerEndpoint = @"https://management.azure.com/",
                    GraphEndpoint = @"https://graph.windows.net/",
                });
```

To this code

```
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory
    .FromServicePrincipal(clientId,
    clientSecret,
    tenantId, 
    AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
```

In case you have some reason that none of the available environment values are good enough, then make sure you initialize all required properties for [AzureEnvironment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.fluent.azureenvironment?view=azure-dotnet)